# updateOrCreate for polymorphic relation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Is there a way to use `updateOrCreate()` or similar method for polymorphic relationship?

Problem with using `updateOrCreate` method I wouldn't know the `id` in the polymorphic table.

Currently doing like this:

```
if ($request->has('meta.description')) {
    $description = $cat->tags()->where('key', 'description')->first();

    if (is_null($description)) {
        $cat->tags()->create([
            'client_id' => client()->id,
            'key'       => 'description',
            'value'     => $request->input('meta.description'),
        ]);
    } else {
        $description->update([
            'value' => $request->input('meta.description'),
        ]);
    }

}
```

Tag method like like this Cat model:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Tag', 'taggable', 'table_name', 'table_id');
}
```

Comment: I don't see the method in your code

Comment: Can not you use `sync` method ?  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: `sync` wouldn't work when using `morphMany()` relation. `Method sync does not exist.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a second parameter to `updateOrCreate`. Try splitting the array up into two like so:

```
$cat->tags()->updateOrCreate(
    [
        'client_id' => client()->id,
        'key'       => 'description'
    ],
    [
        'value'     => $request->input('meta.description')
    ]
);
```